# Is indexing into an array with a signal synthesizable in verilog?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

Are there any problems with synthesizing the following?:

```
 // Read entry
  assign entry[7:0] = my_array[read_address[10:0]][7:0];
```

Where *read_address* is a signal being used to read *my_array*.

I'm used to AND-OR logic for reading an array but I was wondering if the above is 1) synthesizable and 2) what kind of logic it would create?

Comment: I don't have access to a synthesis tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use another variable or expression as an index into an array. The catch is you are only allowed to do this on the RHS of a continuous assignment. You would not be allowed to do the reverse

```
assign my_array[read_address[10:0]] = entry; // illegal
```

Also, there is no need to select `[7:0]` if that is the entire range of the element or signals. In fact that causes problems with signed signals making them unsigned operands.

Comment: but one can use it in lhs of a procedural assignment: `always @* my_array[rad_addres] = entry; ` if declarations and logic are correct.

Comment: @Serge legal for simulation, but not synthesis